# Conditionally joining a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My test tables are:

```
create table products (
  product varchar(50) primary key,
  show_reviews boolean
);
create table reviews (
  review_id integer primary key,
  product varchar(50) references products (product),
  review varchar(200)
);
insert into products (product, show_reviews) values
  ('blender', true),
  ('toaster', false),
  ('microwave', true);
insert into reviews (review_id, product, review) values
  (1, 'blender', 'Excellent'),
  (2, 'toaster', 'Terrible'),
  (3, 'toaster', 'Would not buy again'),
  (4, 'microwave', 'Wonderful'),
  (5, 'microwave', 'Splendid');
```

I'm looking for a query that produces a result set like this:

```
  product    |  show_reviews  |  review_id  |  review
-------------+----------------+-------------+----------
  blender    |  true          |  1          |  Excellent
  toaster    |  false         |  null       |  null
  microwave  |  true          |  4          |  Wonderful
  microwave  |  true          |  5          |  Splendid
```

Essentially, I'd like to conditionally join the `reviews` table depending on the value of `show_reviews`. Here's what I came up with:

```
select products.*, rev.*
from products
left join (
    select reviews.*
    from reviews
    join products as p on p.product = reviews.product
    where p.show_reviews = true
  ) as rev on rev.product = products.product;
```

What are some other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from
    products p
    left join
    reviews r on r.product = p.product and p.show_reviews
;
```

Comment: Excellent. I guess I still don't understand joins as well as I thought I did.